# have somebody with no trial or open process

Tags: grammar

Example with a context (Yahoo news story: [Dissent in Putin’s Russia Just Got More Dangerous](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/dissent-putin-russia-just-got-094500230.html)):

> A law passed earlier this year and signed by President Vladimir Putin made it illegal for Russian citizens to associate with groups designated as undesirable, and also made it possible for Russian prosecutors to **have a group so designated with no trial or open process**.

Slightly reworded, this is what the sentence says: now Russian prosecutors can have groups designated as undesirable with no trial or open process. What do you think *have somebody with no trial or open process* really means? How do you exactly understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"have..[group] ..**so** designated" means "**designate** ....[group] **as [undesirable]**"

So it means the government officials  can **designate** ...*without any [prior] trial or open process.* That is, **declaring** a group "undesirable" can be done secretly, without giving any reason.

It does NOT mean that the groups, or those who associate with them, won't have a "trial or open process" after they are arrested (although that might also be the case, but the article does not say that).

"Designated" is not a mere adjective, it is a verb.  (Compare "have them killed".) so the "without..." phrase is adverb for the verb "designate", not modifier for the noun  "groups".